# Anki: How to get a single deck to show me the back of cards first. Reverse all cards in only one deck

Tags: anki

I want to take a deck that is already made, and simply have it show me the back of the card first. Basically reverse every card in the deck.

If I go to make the basic card type into a reverse card type, then I think that will that change all basic card types in *all* decks into reverse cards? Because I do not want that. I want to only change the cards in one specific deck.

I want, for just this ONE deck, to show me the back of the card first. So basically, "for every single card in this deck and only this deck, show me the back first, and test me on the front". I need to do this in one motion, because there are over 14,000 cards in this deck.

How do I do this? Is it the case that changing the card from basic to basic(reverse) only affects the one deck that the card is from?